# what kind of code google use for detecting real ip while I'm using putty as a sock proxy?

Tags: geolocation, ip, socks

for some reasons I'm using putty as a socks proxy and in 99% of sites my real ip will be hidden from servers but there is an interesting issue in google websites , google can't detect my real IP but can detect my real location.
I'm wondering what kind of code google is using for detecting real location.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

Google use the cookie to watch you regardless your IP

Comment: I'm sure I've disabled my cookie my guess is : using flash or JVM